# Spring Transactional annotation giving CGLIB error

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am getting the following error when using the @Transactional annotation. Any ideas?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepository' defined in file [myFile]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class myRepository]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at myRepository.main(myRepository.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class myRepository]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:217)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitConstructors(Enhancer.java:721)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:499)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
```

Code:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

    private MyDao myDao;


    @Autowired
    public MyRepository(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Object obj) {
        if (obj.isNew())
            myDao.create(obj)

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                      transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" >

 // datasource settings
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given

You need to autowire the field, and either remove the constructor or provide an additional no-argument constructor.

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Object obj) {
        if (obj.isNew())
            myDao.create(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use a `@Transactional` interface instead of a class so CGLIB doesn't need to be involved at all.

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface MyRepository {
    void save(Object obj);
}

public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {
    private final MyDao myDao;

    @Autowired
    public MyRepository(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao
    }

    public void save(Object obj) {
        if (obj.isNew())
            myDao.create(obj)
        }
    }
}
```